# Segmentation Fault and infinite backtrace running MongoDB C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

I have upgraded to boost 1.53.0 so I have to update my MongoDB Driver accordingly (From 2.2.X to 2.4.8).

However, my program using the MongoDB driver now cannot be started. GDB shows that it has gone into some kind of infinite loop.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000415807 in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:114
114         }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000415807 in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:114
#1  0x0000000000418377 in std::auto_ptr<mongo::BSONObjBuilder>::~auto_ptr() () at /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/auto_ptr.h:170
#2  0x0000000000415618 in mongo::BSONObjBuilderValueStream::~BSONObjBuilderValueStream() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonmisc.h:145
#3  0x00000000004157b5 in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:110
#4  0x000000000041580c in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:114
#5  0x0000000000418377 in std::auto_ptr<mongo::BSONObjBuilder>::~auto_ptr() () at /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/auto_ptr.h:170
#6  0x0000000000415618 in mongo::BSONObjBuilderValueStream::~BSONObjBuilderValueStream() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonmisc.h:145
#7  0x00000000004157b5 in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:110
#8  0x000000000041580c in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:114
#9  0x0000000000418377 in std::auto_ptr<mongo::BSONObjBuilder>::~auto_ptr() () at /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/auto_ptr.h:170
#10 0x0000000000415618 in mongo::BSONObjBuilderValueStream::~BSONObjBuilderValueStream() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonmisc.h:145
#11 0x00000000004157b5 in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:110
#12 0x000000000041580c in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:114
#13 0x0000000000418377 in std::auto_ptr<mongo::BSONObjBuilder>::~auto_ptr() () at /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/auto_ptr.h:170
#14 0x0000000000415618 in mongo::BSONObjBuilderValueStream::~BSONObjBuilderValueStream() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonmisc.h:145
#15 0x00000000004157b5 in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:110
#16 0x000000000041580c in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:114
#17 0x0000000000418377 in std::auto_ptr<mongo::BSONObjBuilder>::~auto_ptr() () at /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/auto_ptr.h:170
#18 0x0000000000415618 in mongo::BSONObjBuilderValueStream::~BSONObjBuilderValueStream() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonmisc.h:145
#19 0x00000000004157b5 in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:110
#20 0x000000000041580c in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:114
#21 0x0000000000418377 in std::auto_ptr<mongo::BSONObjBuilder>::~auto_ptr() () at /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/auto_ptr.h:170
#22 0x0000000000415618 in mongo::BSONObjBuilderValueStream::~BSONObjBuilderValueStream() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonmisc.h:145
#23 0x00000000004157b5 in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:110
#24 0x000000000041580c in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:114
#25 0x0000000000418377 in std::auto_ptr<mongo::BSONObjBuilder>::~auto_ptr() () at /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/auto_ptr.h:170
#26 0x0000000000415618 in mongo::BSONObjBuilderValueStream::~BSONObjBuilderValueStream() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonmisc.h:145
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit--- 
#27 0x00000000004157b5 in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:110
#28 0x000000000041580c in mongo::BSONObjBuilder::~BSONObjBuilder() () at /usr/local/include/mongo/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h:114
#29 0x0000000000418377 in std::auto_ptr<mongo::BSONObjBuilder>::~auto_ptr() () at /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/auto_ptr.h:170
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Seems likely an object changed size somewhere and something needs to be recompiled.  Can you recompile your program from scratch (ie. `make clean` or equivalent first)?

Comment: I have tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add the class being serialized?

Comment: Jeremy, Were you able to resolve this? If not, is it possible for you step through your program in GDB and print the context / values where this segfault is being raised? Anil